# Large SVG area is not smoothly scroll-able in mobile

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid mobile app. Some of my pages include large area of interactive SVG images(graphs, charts). I have already added `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to my content area. This helps in smooth scrolling where the SVG image is not there. But when I try to scroll on the SVG, this is not smooth at all.

Please suggest any other work around possible for this kind of problems.

```
.oj-hybrid-applayout-page {

    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use complex/large SVGs if you want to smooth scrolling, they really impact the performance on webview when scrolling. There is nothing you can do to fix that.
If you use images, you should also consider compressing them and not use full blown PNGs where possible.

Also welcome to SO.